# Android: how to give bulletpoints, line break to text in textview

Tags: java, android, textview

i have a textview with large text in it, but i want to give bulletpoints, line breaks , i tried placing xml entities like `&#8226` for bullet point in my `string.xml`, but unable to get linebreak and few text comes in the middle, i like to use justify too

```
String nodata="hi how are you<br/>&#8226welcome to stackoverflow"  
TextView nodata= ((TextView) findViewById(R.id.nodata));
nodata.setText(Html.fromHtml(nodatafound));
```

it kind of works but I am unable to use justify ,
is there any way I can achieve this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Thank you all...i finally ended up doing this

```
String nodata="hi how are you<br/>&#8226;welcome to stackoverflow"
TextView nodata= ((TextView) findViewById(R.id.nodata));
nodata.setText(Html.fromHtml(nodatafound));
```

and for justify left i did change in my layout file `android:layout_gravity=center|left`

i hope there is a betterway doing this.

Answer (score 8):

If you wanna do it in java (I means dynamically) use `\n` for line break and Unicode character for bullet i.e. `\u25CF`.

This is How I'm using it

```
textView.setText("Welcome Username\n\u25CF Some Instructions");
```

It looks as
Welcome Username
● Some Instructions

Your case should be something like

```
textView.setText("hi how are you\n\u25CF welcome to stackoverflow");
```

Here are some code

• = \u2022
● = \u25CF
○ = \u25CB
▪ = \u25AA
■ = \u25A0
□ = \u25A1
► = \u25BA

If you want to do it via xml paste the below text in strings.xml and call this string in xml file

```
hi how are you \n
•  welcome to stackoverflow
```

In strings.xml it would look something like this

```
<string name="welcom_msg">hi how are you \n
•  welcome to stackoverflow</string>
```

Answer (score 5):

place this code in strings.xml

hi how are you  \n

•  welcome to stackoverflow

set this text to your textview

Comment: <string name="text">hi how are you \n

 •&#160; welcome to stackoverflow \n
 </string>  and set text to your textview in your xml file    android:text="@string/text"

Comment: what is this "&#160;" entity for ? some text is cooming in the middle how to justify to rightside?

Answer (score 4):

You forgot the colon after `&#8226;`

So change  it to this:

```
String nodata="hi how are you<br/>&#8226;welcome to stackoverflow"
TextView nodata= ((TextView) findViewById(R.id.nodata));
nodata.setText(Html.fromHtml(nodatafound));
```

Comment: i am sorry ..actually the question is without this quote marks ""..i edited

Answer (score 0):

Try this out:

```
String s = "hello world"
           + System.getProperty ("line.separator")
           + "hello android"
           + System.getProperty ("line.separator");
```

Answer (score 0):

Add in string.xml file

`<string name="str">&#8226;item 1\n &#8226;item 2 \n &#8226; item 3</string>`